# Does there exists a continuously differentiable function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ and $\forall_{x,y} f(f(x,y))=(o,x)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does there exists a continuously differentiable function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ and $\forall_{x,y} f(f(x,y))=(0,x)$?

---

Here is what I have:

Define $g(x,y)=f(f(x,y))=(0,x)$.
We have that $det(Dg)=det(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix})=0$.

Using the chain rule and $f(0,0)=(0,0)$, we get $0=det(Dg|_0)=det(Df(f(x,y))|_0Df(x,y)|_0)=det(\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}|_{(0,0)} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}|_{(0,0)}\\\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}|_{(0,0)} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}|_{(0,0)}\end{bmatrix}^2)=det((Df|_0)^2) \implies det(Df|_0)=0$.

I'm not sure how to continue from here. Any clues?

Comment: Look at the chain rule without taking determinants.

Comment: You're consistently writing your desired result as $(o,x)$ -- does that mean something different from $(0,x)$?

Comment: Thanks @KennyWong, I got it.

Comment: And thanks @henningMakhold for pointing that out, it was just a recurring typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @KennyWong, we can continue from my original post without taking the determinant.

Denoting $x_1=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}|_{(0,0)}, x_2=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}|_{(0,0)}, y_1=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}|_{(0,0)}, y_2=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}|_{(0,0)}$, we have that:

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & y_1\\x_2 & y_2\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2+y_1x_2 & x_1y_1+y_1y_2\\x_2x_1+y_2x_2 & y_2^2+y_1x_2\end{bmatrix}$.

By the top right corner of the metrices, we have that $y_1=0$ or $x_1=-y_2$.
If $y1=0$, then by the top left corner we get $x_1=0$, and that is a contradiction to the bottom left corner.
If $x_1=-y_2$, then again we get a contradiction to the bottom left corner.